# i18next in React Native: import {t} doesn't work (works in React Web)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, i18next

The following code works in normal React project (I'm using typescript, if it matters):

```
import {t} from "i18next";

const translation = t('WelcomeMessage');
```

the very same code doesn't work in React Native project giving an error:

```
import i18n, {t} from "i18next";

const translation1 = i18n.t('WelcomeMessage');   //works ok
const translation = t('WelcomeMessage'); //ERROR: (0, _i18next.t) is not a function
```

why `t('WelcomeMessage')` doesn't work in RNative? Does it have something to do with how i18next is exported in typedefinitions (`export = i18next;`)?

Comment: Is `react-i18next` not an option?

Comment: I just don't need it. I'm actually ok with using `i18n.t('SomeString')` everywhere, I'm just curious why it doesn't work

Comment: I mean, I'm curious why `t('WelcomeMessage')` doesn't work in RNative

Comment: It should be related to metro bundler.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality using `i18n-js`
https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/releases

create a `.js` file.

```
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

import en from '../translations/en.json';
import ar from '../translations/ar.json';

i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, ar };

export default i18n;
```

In component class call this i18n.js file

```
import i18n from './i18n'
class Test extends Component {

   render(){
     return(
        <Text>i18n.t('sample')</Text>
     )
   }

}
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting the benefits of your answer. `i18n.t('sample')` already works for me. It's `t('sample')` (without `i18n.`) that doesn't work in React Native. In your example you are using `i18n.t('sample')` at the end, which already works for me